# Incorrect consistently of events

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I started learn JS and WebApi.Net
My problem: part_2 performed before part_1, but sometimes it's work correctly.

```js
//**** <part_1> ****
var link = 'api/Values',
  ttMass = new Array(); //make ToolTip array

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(link, {
    i: 1
  }, function(data) { //http-response as 'api/Values/1'
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
      ttMass.push(val);
    });
  });
});
//**** </part_1> ****

//**** <part_2> ****        
$(document).ready(function() { //
  $.get(link, {
    i: 0
  }, function(data) { //http-response as 'api/Values/0'
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
      $(sel).append('<option value="' + val + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="' + ttMass[i] + '">' + val + '</option>'); //fill <select> values and ToolTip
    });
  });
});
//**** </part_2> ****
```

How making this parts consistently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.get` calls are asynchronous, therefore the order of their response cannot be guaranteed as it is down to the speed of the recipient server.

If you need to guarantee that they execute in order, place one call within the callback of the other.

Also note that your `ttMass` array is redundant as it contains the exact same values as returned in `data`, so you could use that directly without the `each()` loop. Try this:

```
var link = 'api/Values';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(link, { i: 1 }, function(ttMass) {
    $.get(link, { i: 0 }, function(data) {
      var html = data.map(function(val, i) {
        return '<option value="' + val + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="' + ttMass[i] + '">' + val + '</option>';
      });
      $(sel).append(html);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your last code working. Thanks.
But about this code. I don't understand where you fill `ttMass`

Comment: `$.get(link, { i: 1 }, function(ttMass) {` <--

Comment: Thank you. Now i know more.